# What's the subordinate clause type for these two that-clause sentences below?

Tags: grammar, american-english, which-that

I am always confused about what type of subordinate clause "that" can connect. So there are two sentence below:

1. So far the torpedo has proved a damp squib, with observers arguing **that** Europe has not gained any leverage to press its demands.
2. Afflictions has take place in Syrian on June 3th **that** his job to negotiate political settlement and establish transitional governing body would be pointless.

I am curious what the sub-clause type after "that" for above two sentences? Because each main clause doesn't miss any grammatical ingredient, so I thought these that-clause are appositive clause.

Comment: I agree with Cerberus, your second sentence isn't right.  For it to be grammatical, it'd need to be something like *Afflictions **have** taken place in **Syria** **such** that his job to negotiate **a** political settlement and establish **a** transitional governing body would be pointless*, although it's still a bit odd sounding (maybe you mean *actions* rather than *afflictions*?).  Also, you can still use *June **3rd***, but to do so you need to change the verb from *have taken* to *took*.

Comment: Note that the second sentence is simply a poor transcription of "*No successor has been named to replace the elder statesman, who recently said that if **elections take place in Syria on June 3, his job — to negotiate a political settlement and establish a transitional governing body — would be pointless***" from [this article](http://www.voanews.com/content/un-special-envoy-to-syria-resigns/1913715.html).

Comment: @DanBron thank you for providing the original article. I found the second poor sentence from a English listening training forum...

Comment: @DanBron nice find!

Comment: See also: [ell.se] Good Luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first *that* clause is an **object clause**, because it functions as the object of *arguing*. It is not appositive, because it is simply an object on its own.

The second example is not written in proper English; I would dismiss it.